# How to create a chart Report using Query calculation and displaying date dynamically more than 12 months

Tags: cognos-10

I need to create a Chart Report where I need to display the data rolling 12 months and more than 12 months.For example, my Cognos Report is displaying data from Dec2018 to Dec 2019 but post 2019 it should reflect date from Dec 2019 to Dec 2020.

Also, there is a summary sheet below which has values against KPI's and applying some calculations on those value, I need to show in Report.Like, there is a value in KPI (98765) for Dec 2018 and I need to reflect (98765/1000) above.A sample Report is provided below.

Comment: What version of Cognos 10?
Are you using Workspace or Report Studio?
What kind of chart?
Are you trying to figure out the filter needed?

Answer (score 0):

Try this Filter

```
[Date] >= _add_years(_add_days(current_date, -1), -1)
```

Then for the measures

Definition for the data item rolling 12

```
IF([Date] <= current_date)Then([Measure])Else(0)
```

Definition for the data item post

```
IF([Date] < current_date)Then([Measure])Else(0)
```